# Downloadable attachment in salesforce

Tags: salesforce

I need to create attachment that can be downloaded clicking on a link how to do it in salesforce
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can implement it with Visualforce page and controller.

On VF page you need to use something like:

```
<a href="/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file={!attachmentInstance.Id}"  target="_blank">{!attachmentInstance.Name}</a>
```

And in controller you can use SOQL query to Attachment object, like:

```
List<Attachment>attch = [Select Id, Name from Attachments];
```

Comment: Agree with the approach, but my suggestion would be to use: {!URLFOR($Action.Document.Download, attachmentInstance.Id)}